# Script references inserted in the header

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I inherited an older CF site and trying to move it to a different server. There's a problem with the scripts references in the header. They are not accessible and I get a 404 error when trying to navigate to them.

I searched through all my code to find where these scripts could be included, but to no avail.

Does ColdFusion insert references like these automatically or am I missing some source code?

[image]

Comment: These are automatically added to the head by coldfusion when you use custom tags that need them. There should be a mapping to them on your web server. If not, they exist in the coldfusion directory or they were added to your web root during the install.

Comment: I don’t mean “custom tags”... I meant built in coldfusion tags that use JavaScript.

Comment: @Redtopia: Your comments really are the answer. You may want to consider writing it up as an answer. I might add a bit about `<cfform>`, but other than that it is spot on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using ColdFusion tags that require javascript, the javascript source files will be automatically added to the `<head>` element of your page. This includes `<cfform>` `<cfinput>` as well as other non-form related tags, like `<cfgrid>` and `<cfgraph>`.

These source files can be found in either the ColdFusion install directory, or it's also possible that the CF installer added them to your web root folder, which would be install-dependent. Depending on your install, a mapping may have been made in your web server to the `cf_scripts` folder, which would give your app access to those files.

As an aside, I personally avoid using coldfusion tags that inject javascript. I prefer to have complete control over the javascript libs that I use, and I don't like to rely on ColdFusion to release bug fixes, add enhancements, or maintain compatibility.

Comment: The only thing I would add is, Javascript in general changes faster than ColdFusion's Javascript. There are new Javascript things to tap into, that will never be a part of ColdFusion 11's Javascript .

Comment: Absolutely right @JamesAMohler. Don't get stuck with ColdFusion javascript code in your apps!!!! It will be that way for decades!